# Python Telegram Bot (InlineQueryResult) Message Content

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am working on a telegram bot, I am running into an issue with the `InlineQueryResultArticle`. I have a function `get_player_stats(player_id)` where the id being passed through gives me a second json set allow me to get more information and get my return message text. The issue I am running into though, is once the `inline_query_handler` is called, it runs the `inline_player_list` which then builds the `result_article list` including the `input_message`...All I want is a way to delay the input_message being built until a user selects an article first

```
async def inline_query_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    query = update.inline_query.query
    player_info = inline_player_list()
    print("inline started")

    if not query:  # Empty query, return the entire stats list
        print("query empty")
        await update.inline_query.answer(player_info)  # Call the function to get the list
    else:
        print("query updated")
        # Filter the stats_list based on the user's query
        filtered_player_info = [item for item in player_info if query.lower() in item.title.lower()]

        # Answer the inline query with the filtered results
        await update.inline_query.answer(filtered_player_info)
```

```
def inline_player_list():
    player_info = players.get_active_players()[:10]
    stats_list = []  # Create a new list to hold the player information
    headshot_url = "https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/latest/260x190/"

    for player in player_info:
        player_id = player['id']
        player_name = player['full_name']

        result_article = InlineQueryResultArticle(
            thumbnail_url=f"{headshot_url}{player_id}.png",
            thumbnail_width=32,
            thumbnail_height=32,
            id=player_id,
            title=player_name,
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(get_player_stats(player_id), parse_mode="HTML"))

        stats_list.append(result_article)

    return stats_list
```

I have tried using InlineQueries but none really worked out for text.